# Invoking TaskbarItemInfo in C#, to avoid using .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, progress-bar, pinvoke

I would like to know if it is possible to change the ProgressValue and ProgressState of an application using P/Invoke, so that I do not have to change my .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0. Thanks ahead of time.